# Lemniscate Figure Eight Question

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

This is a problem on a previous examination.

My question is on part C in which I have no clue how to answer. Any hints? Thank you.

Comment: *Hint:*  write down explicitly what a continuous deformation from $\gamma$ to $\mu$ would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very nice exercise!

There is deeper reasons why the answer of C is NO, but is this context, you have to use A and B:

in A, you compute the residue of f at 1 and -1, then take the sum cause the index is 1 for each,

in B, you take the difference cause the index is 1 at 1 and -1 at -1,
so you find 2 differents results.

You conclude with the fact that the integral is homotopy (here continuous deformation) invariant when the two singularities are contained in the compact complement of the closed curve you are integrating on! You knew this fact? Or we can prove it, but it's probably in your complex analysis lecture.

Comment: Wow very neat! I'll look it up. I hate to be tested on things that were never on lecture.

Comment: Back many moons ago, my complex analysis prof. used homotopy in the proof of the Cauchy-Goursat theorem.  It was a very nice way to learn about both the theorem and an important topology concept in one sitting.  In fact, it was the one place in which he deviated from Ahlfors, who only mentions the concept in his mixed-bag chapter at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you had such a deformation $\gamma_s$ as $s$ goes from $0$ to $1$, with $\gamma_0 = \gamma$ and $\gamma_1 = \mu$. You could compute the integral over each $\gamma_s$, and it would vary continuously as a function of $s$. It would also be *constant* as a function of $s$ (each one can be computed by the residue theorem). But parts a and b show that the integral for $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ are different. So there cannot be a deformation.